# Is it possible to pipe directly into stargazer?

Tags: r, pipe, stargazer

Is it possible to pipe directly into stargazer, instead of using the more complicated way as followed?

Example:

```
date %>%
  filter(x1== "yes",
         x2 == "no") %>% 
  select(x5,
         x6) -> df
  
cols <- c("x5", "x6") 

stargazer(
    df[, cols], type = "text", 
    summary.stat = c("min", "p25", "mean", "p75", "max", "median", "sd", "n") 
)
```

Comment: `df[, cols] %>% stargazer(type = "text", ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to directly pipe the result of `select` in `stargazer`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stargazer)

mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 6) %>%
  select(wt, disp, cyl) %>%
  stargazer(type = "text", 
            summary.stat = c("min", "p25", "mean", "p75", "max", "median", "sd", "n"))

=================================================================
Statistic  Min  Pctl(25)  Mean   Pctl(75)  Max  Median St. Dev. N
-----------------------------------------------------------------
wt        2.620  2.822    3.117   3.440   3.460 3.215   0.356   7
disp       145    160    183.314  196.3    258  167.6   41.562  7
cyl         6      6      6.000     6       6     6     0.000   7
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stargazer)
df %>%
    select(all_of(cols)) %>%
    stargazer(type = "text", 
        summary.stat = c("min", "p25", "mean", "p75", "max", "median", "sd", "n"))
```